# Compare two fields with OGC filter in OL3 and GeoServer

Tags: openlayers-3, geoserver

I'm using Opeonlayers 3.18 + GeoServer. I can make a ogc filter for comparing a field and a value. How can i compare two fields?
Code below shows what i'm looking for:

```
var f = ol.format.ogc.filter.greaterThan('Field1', 100);  // this works nicely
var f = ol.format.ogc.filter.greaterThan('Field1', 'Field2'); // this doesn't work
```

Equivalent working CQL filter is: 'Field1 > Field2'

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This sort of filtering should work.  I'd note that many databases may not have a way to perform that filter in an optimal way, and as such, there's a chance that the handling for such a filter is not correct.

The first thing to check out is if the GeoServer logs have any additional information.  For most requests, there are log messages which will provide all the details (including the filter) for the request.

If OL3 is making a non-sense request, there should be some kind of parse error first.  If the datastore is having trouble with the request, you might see an exception.

To help further, which version of GeoServer and which datastore are you using?  Also, is there additional information in the logs?

**Update**:  Based on the comment below, I checked out the Open Layers 3 source.  If you look [here](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/v3.18.0/src/ol/format/wfs.js#L643-L649), it looks like OL3 is treating the first argument as a properyName and the second as a literal.  It is probably worth filling a bug/feature request on the project's GitHub page.

Comment: Its Geoserver 2.8.2 and shapefile layer and both fields are of type Long. GeoServer just returns an empty response and its log says that: "Unable to parse filter: ... <Filter xmlns=".."><PropertyIsGreaterThan><PropertyName>Field1</PropertyName><Literal>Field2</Literal></PropertyIsGreaterThan></Filter></Query></GetFeature>".  If i make a text-plain filter by changing that Literal tag to PropertyName tag, now Openlayers returns error: "TypeError: filter.getTagName is not a function. ol.xml.makeSimpleNodeFactory(filter.getTagName()),".

Comment: Thanks. If the second argument shouldn't be Literal -in this case- , then what it must be? I mean what is the correct and standard filter for this case?

Comment: The second argument would need to be a PropertyName.

My guess is that when you tried to make it a PropertyName in the JavaScript, OL3 was unhappy since it is expecting the second argument to be a literal.